# Convert object property numeric value to string and append to object as new key value

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
0: {Number: 1 }
1: {Number: 2 }
```

I am using lodash and react. I cant convert the number to a string but not add the value back into the output. I need something that looks like this:

```
0: {Number: 1, newNumber:"1" }
1: {Number: 2, newNumber: "2" }
```

I tried using .push, but this just added it as a new object e.g.

```
0: {Number: 1, }
1: {Number: 2, } 
3: {newNumber: "1"}
```

I can't push into its corresponding object...

Comment: i cant understand the question. is number the prop name in the object?

Comment: do you have an array or an object as outer data structure? please add what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the data with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and add the additinal key to the Object:

```js
var data = [{Number: 1 }, {Number: 2 }];

var result = data.map(el => ({...el, newNumber: String(el.Number)}))

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `Array.map`

```js
var x = [{
  Number: 1
}, {
  Number: 2
}];

var y = x.map(el => {
  el.newNumber = el.Number.toString();
  return el;
});

console.log(y);
```